# rails joins query with conditions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble with a query i've been working on.  I want to include a condition with this.

```
FooDiscount.where(bar_code_id: object.id).joins(foo: [:foo_items]).sum(:quantity)
```

This will return the correct quantity I need, but i'm looking to add a condition to `.joins(foo: [:foo_items])`  I only want to return `foo_items` if `foo.order_status.code != "cancelled"`

Update:

Earlier I didn't mention that a `foo` can have_many `order_statuses`.  So that query is giving me incorrect results.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `order_status` is a db-backed model it should be something along these lines (might be issues with singular/plural, but you get the idea):

```
FooDiscount
  .where(bar_code_id: object.id)
  .joins(foo: [:foo_items, :order_statuses])          # edit joining
  .where.not(order_statuses: { code: 'cancelled' }) # your condition
  .sum('foo_discounts.quantity')                    # ensure no issues with determining,
                                                    # which table's column quantity is
```

Comment: I was about to thumbs-up but the what happens if `foo` has_many: order_status and they are in different states (like some are 'cancelled' but the current is 'open')  Then he would want to create an association `has_one :current_order_status` if just cares about current possibly or `has_many :canceled_order_status` if he cares if it has ever been canceled

Comment: @drhenner judging from OP's foo.order_status.code its has_one, so don't hesitate to thumb-up ;)

Comment: If it is a belongs_to a faster query would be to cache the `order_status_id` that == "cancelled".  then `.where.not(foo: { order_status_id: OrderStatus.CANCELED_ID })` without the extra order_status join

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I made a mistake and updated my answer.  Foo can actually `have_many` `order_statuses` and if any of those statuses are canceled, then I would not like to include it.

Comment: @Jay let me edit the answer (but the edit will by tiny and you could have guessed it ;))

Comment: @Jay play with it a bit just to understand what's going on, see the generated SQL etc..